# How do I change the default ignore_modifiers in AwesomeWM?

Tags: awesome-wm

From the [documentation of awful.key](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.key.html), I can see that the default ignore_modifiers is "Lock" and "Mod2". How do I add an additional modifier to this list so that its state does not affect the functioning of Awesome?